# DI-контейнер должен быть глобальный?

Tags: php

Начал изучать DI-контейнеры, мне очень нравится реализация `Pimple` (готов также рассмотреть примеры на symfony DI).

Вопрос первый, комплексный:

Должен ли DI контейнер быть глобальным для проекта? 
Т.е. при разработке приложения, в одном месте я помещаю и туда сервисы и конфигурирую их, а в другим местах приложения (других файлах) получаю эти сервисы?

Как это делается? В рахных файлах (классах) я могу добавлять сервисы в контейнер ? Тогда возможны случаи, когда при попытке получить сервис, его не окажется.. Т.е. вызов сервиса до объявления. Как быть с этим?

Или лучше в одном месте добавлять все сервисы и зависимости? Как это делают другие?

1. Как должен инициализироваться DI контейнер, чтобы был доступен во всех файлов проекта? 
   Правильно понимаю, что либо глобальная переменная, либо singleton ? Или как?

Answer (score 0):

Добавлять все сервисы и зависимости следует в одном месте.
В объектно-ориентированном приложении не должно быть ни глобальных переменных, ни синглтона. Этого сложно избежать, и проще всего скатиться по простой дорожке к синглтону. Но это приведет к проблемам в будущем.
Есть два подхода. Это либо явное объявление всех классов с их зависимостями, как это принято в Симфони  3.хх, либо магия - рефлекшен похуже, аннотации получше, но тоже так себе.

То есть, когда мы просим систему создать новый объект, у нас уже есть информация о том, какие объекты ему понадобятся в качестве аргументов, и контейнер подставит инстансы требуемых сервисов.

Comment: Спасибо! А каким образом должен инициализироваться DI-контейнер, чтобы был доступен в моих классах.

Структура CMS в котором работаю следующая: есть системный файл init.php, который подключается после подключения всех служебных скриптов системы. А этом файле init.php я подключаю файл autoload.php композера, через композер настроена автозагрузка файлов по psr-4.  Правильно понимаю, что мне просто нужно после подключения файла autoload надо инициализировать DI-iконтейнер ? и просто им пользоваться в классах ? Но ведь тогда этоа переменная будет глобальной..

Comment: вот так объявляю контейнер.
http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2019/07/08/0037/0052/2453556/56/a0b0dca7e1.jpg

а в классе, который подключается через автозагрузчик, делаю так: 
http://dl4.joxi.net/drive/2019/07/08/0037/0052/2453556/56/ad8fab3446.jpg

а конфигурацию - добавление сервиса в контейнер, делаю перед использованием класса в котором вызываю сервис?